# Slow Mutlisite Performance

Tags: wordpress, performance, .htaccess

We have a multisite WordPress network that is based on SubFolders, and we've had some issues regarding the overall performance of the network.

The problem is that all the network sites have a very slow performance when they login, edit post, edit page, view themes, view plugins or any other activities.

We've tried to follow up the problem and we temporarily solved it by switching all sites to this theme: http://www.justskins.com/wordpress-themes/curved-wordpress-theme/22
and by also disabling functions.php on this theme. After this all the sites are working fast with no lag. But we need to enable users to choose themes and use them.

Here's our htaccess file configuration:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress

AddType application/octet-stream .rar

<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

Our server is:
Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2
with an Apache2.2 server installed.

Our base URL is sites.iugaza.edu.ps , could anyone help us resolve this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief rundown for you. Kindly note that it is always **highly discouraged** to run a PHP web server on a Windows environment. PHP is designed primarily to run on Linux and some features may not be available on Windows.

There are a couple of open source and free solutions that can help resolve the problem: Ubuntu Linux, based on Debian, acts as a simple replacement that you can run side-by-side with Windows, and it enjoys great ease-of-use, security, and stability. Many governmental services use it internally, whether as a desktop or server platform.

1) **Nginx** as a replacement for Apache. WordPress.com runs on Nginx for example.

Nginx handles concurrency graciously on every level, and it is extremely easy to deploy for WordPress. Nginx is available for Windows, but true performance once again comes from running it in a Linux environment.

http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-multisite-wordpress-nginx/

2) **HHVM** as a replacement for simple PHP.

HHVM is an alternative to PHP developed internally by Facebook to suit hundreds of millions of users. It is practically completely compatible with PHP, MySQL, and specfically with WordPress.

For a multisite installation, this can reduce your costs significantly while improving performance tremendously.

http://www.computersnyou.com/3276/2014/05/setup-nginx-hhvm-mysql-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-step-step/